# Sql Server Reporting Services 2008: How to remove hyperlink in excel export?

Tags: reporting-services

i've a table, where some cell have an action: Go to report (to a detail report).
When user click, SSRS send user to the sub report. 
But i need to cancel the hyperlink when user export the report in excel. How can i do ? I know exists **Globals!RenderFormat** but i don't know how to use it to tell SSRS not to export hyperlink.

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to go to the Action section on the cell which has the hyperlink.  You probably have set the "Go to Report" action.  Instead of just specifying the report, you'll need to specify an expression for it instead, something like this:

```
IIf(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", Nothing, "YourReportPath")
```

OR you could also use the .IsInteractive property, which will disable the links for PDF exports as well:

```
IIf(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive, "YourReportPath", Nothing)
```